# IllegalStateException after using lifeCycleScope

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment, kotlin-stateflow

I have used **viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope** and also tried converted `uploadPhoto` **StateFlow** to **LiveData** but still my App crashes at dismiss loadingDialogFragment

**LoadingDialogFragment.kt**

```
class LoadingDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var mBinding: DialogLoaderBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
        isCancelable = false
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        mBinding = DialogLoaderBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return mBinding.root
    }

    override fun show(manager: FragmentManager, tag: String?) {
        ///super.show(manager, tag)
        try {
            val ft: FragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
            ft.add(this, tag).addToBackStack(null)
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            Log.e("IllegalStateException", "Exception", e)
        }
    }
}
```

**ProfileFragment -> onViewCreated**

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                mViewModel.uploadPhoto.collectLatest {
                    if (it.isLoading) {
                        loadingDialogFragment = LoadingDialogFragment()
                        loadingDialogFragment?.show(childFragmentManager, "loadingDialogFragment")
                    }
                    it.error?.let {
                        loadingDialogFragment?.dismiss() //crashed at here 
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "No ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()

                    }

                    it.data?.let {
                        loadingDialogFragment?.dismiss() //crashed at here 
                    }
            }
        }
```

As far as my understanding is concern collectLatest code should not work when app activity or fragment is in onPause|onStop or onDestroy state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I have faced this similar issue as well**

- I have solved this issue by using

  ```
  viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
  viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
   // {code to collect from viewModel}
   }
  }
  ```

So , your code would be look like

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                mViewModel.uploadPhoto.collectLatest {
                    if (it.isLoading) {
                        loadingDialogFragment = LoadingDialogFragment()
                        loadingDialogFragment?.show(childFragmentManager, "loadingDialogFragment")
                    }
                    it.error?.let {
                        loadingDialogFragment?.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "No ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                    it.data?.let {
                        loadingDialogFragment?.dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

- ***How it works***

***repeatOnLifecycle** **is a suspend function***. As such, it needs to be executed within a *coroutine*. ***repeatOnLifecycle*** suspends the calling coroutine, and then runs a given suspend block that you pass as a parameter in a new coroutine each time the given lifecycle reaches a target state or higher. If the lifecycle state falls below the target, the coroutine launched for the block is cancelled. Lastly, the ***repeatOnLifecycle*** function itself won’t resume the calling coroutine until the lifecycle is ***DESTROYED***.